# Relationship between reaction quotient and potential energy

Tags: thermodynamics, free-energy, molecular-dynamics

I am trying to calculate the Gibbs free energy in an NVT simulation. Although

$$\Delta G = -RT\ln Q,$$

in my simulation I can't calculate

$$Q = \frac{[\text{Products}]}{[\text{Reactants}]}$$

because I cant determine the concentrations of reactants and products.

Hence, I am looking for a relationship between reaction quotient $Q$ and potential energy $U$ as well as $p,$ $V,$ $T,$ i.e.

$$Q(U,p,V,T) = ?$$

Comment: $G$ itself is not equal to $RT \ln Q$; you either want $$\Delta_\mathrm{r}G ^\circ = -RT\ln K,$$ or $$\Delta_\mathrm{r} G = \Delta_\mathrm{r} G^\circ + RT \ln Q.$$ Aside from that, I'm highly skeptical that one can find a relationship between $Q$ and $U$, assuming that by $U$ you mean "the total internal energy of the system".

Comment: Did you meant ["reaction quotient"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_quotient) instead of [reaction coordinate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_coordinate)?

Comment: @orthocresol I am looking for U as potential energy. Forgive my lack of proficiency with the terms, if total internal energy is essentially the same as potential energy.

Comment: Terminology aside, your first equation is still concerning, to me at least.

Comment: @orthocresol yes you are right w.r.t. the equation. However, since I will be calculating the Gibb's Free energy at each frame, I can calculate the difference without the equilibrium gibbs free energy as that would be the common term in all energies and the end result I am looking for is the difference.

Comment: Even so, then you should write $\Delta \Delta G = RT\ln \left( \frac{Q_2}{Q_1} \right)$. Also, you should use the Helmholtz free energy - not Gibbs - if working in NVT.

Comment: @BuckThorn why should I use helmholtz instead of Gibbs for NVT?  Is there a resource you can cite for this? I am trying to use eq2 from this [paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jp981922f) and it uses G for the free energy so I assumed it has to be gibbs

Comment: The equation you are thinking of (if not actually writing) assumes the pressure is constant, which it isn't in NVT.

Comment: @BuckThorn could you please mention the eqution you're talking about.

Comment: The same one orthocresol mentions in the first comment

Comment: Maybe try googling "NVT ensemble Helmholtz", I hit this for instance: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Among_NVT_and_NPT_ensemble_which_one_is_preferable_during_MD_simulation

Comment: You might also want to post your question over at the material modeling site. It might be more appropriate there.